# I need to set up humioexternal cluster . How to set up?

Tags: resources, monitoring, humio

I need to set up humioexternal cluster . How to set up ?

Codes and explanation for setting up humioexternalcluster

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.